# pointer giving unexpected value

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am reading Understanding Pointers in c.

I found one program here it is.

```
#include<Stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    static int arr[]={97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104};
    int *ptr=arr+1;
    printf("\nThe base Address is:%u\n",arr);
    print(++ptr,ptr--,ptr,ptr++,++ptr);
    return getch();
}

print(int *a,int *b,int *c,int *d,int *e)
{
      printf("%d  %d  %d  %d  %d",*a,*b,*c,*d,*e);
}
```

**The program is perfect what i think is that it must generate following output: 99 99 98 98 100.
But it gives following output: 100 100 100 99 99**

I am unable to understand help me to understand it.

Comment: "The program is perfect" - famous last words.

Comment: How often do we get this exact question?

Comment: Hi @google, please google for your question before asking here. So many duplicates have already been answered here.

Comment: Dan and 0xF1: It is kind of funny (or at least oxymoronic) when the question is asked by a user called google.

Comment: @dan at least once a week, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the order of evaluation of function parameters being unspecified, the program sports several items with undefined behavior:

- It tries to access the value of an expression with side effects before reaching the next sequence point (it does that several times in the call of `print`), and
- It tries printing a pointer using `%u` format specifier.

The way the program is written it can print anything at all, not print anything, or even crash: that's the consequences of having undefined behavior.

If you want the evaluation of parameters to be in a specific order, introduce temporary variables, and do evaluation sequentially, like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    static int arr[]={97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104};
    int *ptr=arr+1;
    printf("\nThe base Address is:%p\n",(void*)arr);
    int *tmp0 = ++ptr;
    int *tmp1 = ptr--;
    int *tmp2 = ptr;
    int *tmp3 = ptr++;
    int *tmp4 = ++ptr;
    print(tmp0, tmp1, tmp2, tmp3, tmp4);
    return getch();
}
print(int *a,int *b,int *c,int *d,int *e)
{
      printf("%d  %d  %d  %d  %d",*a,*b,*c,*d,*e);
}
```

Comment: You can also include the `<Stdio.h>`, in the 'perfect program'

Comment: thanks this is knowledgable answer and i really feeling good to understand this.

Answer (score 2):

```
print(++ptr,ptr--,ptr,ptr++,++ptr);
```

is undefined behaviour because the order in which the parameters are evaluated is not specified by the C standard.